# What is student A and B z-score?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

What is students’ A and B z-score? if $mean=81$, $SD=4$, distribution is normally distributed.
(student A scored $72$, and student B scored $86$).
what is the $z-score$ value for both student A and student B

student A $z-score(72) = (72 - mean)/SD = (72 - 81)/4 = - 2.25$

student B $z-score(86) = (86 - mean)/SD = (86 - 81)/4 = - 1.25$

now the question is what is the $z-score$ value for both student A and student B, is it:

1- student A $z-score$ + student B $z-score$ = $- 2.25 + - 1.25 = - 3.5$

or

2- student A and student B $z-score(72+86)$ = $z-score(153) = (153 - mean)/SD = (153 - 81)/4 = 18$

Or when it comes to calculate more than 0ne $z-score$ together, we should use another way?
Thanks

Comment: A z-score only corresponds to one measurement. You cannot combine them.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, I don't know why my lecturer wants us to answer it

Comment: From context, the exercise asks for the scores of both students, not some sort of combined score.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right, thanks a lot for the help :)